# Show drop down list onclick others element (text input)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a text input (z-index:1) which i put in front of the drop down box. So that the user can input text and also choose from drop down list. I did hide the down arrow button for the drop down list. So, I want when user click on the text input, the drop down listing will automatic display. I plan to used Jquery to display the listing, but i don't know what function that I need to use.

Here my code

```
    <span id="plantimefromdd" style="position:relative;">
        <input id="textin1" name="textin1" type="text" style="width:100px;position:absolute;top:-4px;left:13;z-index:1;padding:3;margin:0;opacity:0;" value="<?php echo $todisplay; ?>" onclick="this.style.opacity=1;">
        <?php
        //display dropdown time for from interval 5 minutes
        $start = strtotime('12:00am');
        $end = strtotime('11:55pm');

        echo '<select name="plantimefromdd" style="width:100px;height:26px;-webkit-appearance:none;border-width:2px;border-color:#D8D8D8;" onchange="$(\'input#textin1\').val($(this).val());">';

        for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += 300){
            $timerfrom = date('H:i', $i);
            if($todisplay == $timerfrom) {$temp = "selected";} else {$temp = "";}
            echo '<option '.$temp.' >' . $timerfrom ;
                }
        echo '</select>';
        ?>
    </span>
```

Thank you for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

First add id to your drop-down and then for the text-box make the following from:

```
onclick="this.style.opacity=1;"
```

To:

```
onclick="$('#dropdown').show()" onblur="$('#dropdown').hide()"
```

Comment: but this one will hide and show the entire dropdown..i want to hide and show the listing of the dropdown..